# Focus back on outlook after user closes window

Tags: javascript, html, outlook

1. An email link, expected to be opened from outlook, will direct to the application. When the new window/tab is closed by user, how to direct him back to outlook (focus back on outlook)?
2. Is there any generic way to set focus on outlook (already open)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate?